# Fixing ordering of nodes and color (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

This is my first time using TikZ. I can't figure out how to change the ordering of the nodes from bottom up starting from the bottom left corner?

Also, when I try to use package `xcolor` midnightblue doesn't work. Why is this? How can I get it to work?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=midnightblue!25,minimum size=4}]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi) (\y\x)--(\yi\x) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `y=-1cm` to the TikZ picture’s option would be one way. Or simply using `\node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\label};}` (note the `-`). — For future MWEs, please see [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Man, this is really overwhelming... Does that mean it's not a good idea to use this code?

Comment: Other advice: instead of `\x\y` (Ex: `00`, ..., `44`), use `a-\x-\y` (ex: `a-0-0`, ..., `a-4-4`) to name your nodes.

Comment: While the `minimal` class works quite good for simple TikZ pictures, it is not a class for minimal WEs. Simply use `article` or the `standalone` class (which, setup correctly, can automatically produce `.png` files). The [tag:standalone] class even has a `tikz` option which a) loads the `tikz` package automatically and b) crops the PDF so that you only have the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `-y` for the placement coordinate if you want to start at the bottom and work up. Also the color is `MidnightBlue` and it requires the use of the `[dvipsnames]` option:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=MidnightBlue!25,minimum size=4}]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\label};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi) (\y\x)--(\yi\x) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you desire the numbering to start at the bottom left and go up then you need to alter the computation of the `\label`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=MidnightBlue!25,minimum size=4}]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{5*\x  + \y + 1}
       \node [thick, darkstyle, minimum size=2.5em]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi) (\y\x)--(\yi\x) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I get the node sizes to be uniform?

Comment: To get uniform node sizes, you can either use something like `minimum size=2.0em`, or make each label the same size using a `\makebox`.

Comment: Using `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before the `documentclass` might save some headache for later.

Comment: @AlanH: Have updated the solution, but that is more of math issue rather than a TeX issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill Bah. Thank you so much. I just realize how it works.

Comment: @AlanH: Your welcome. Must be more difficult due to the extreme cold temperature of where you are. :-)